# dozer mapping list field

Tags: list, mapping, dozer

I've the following situation:

```
class A {
   private String name;
   private List<R> rs = new ArrayList<R>();
   //get, set
}

class R {
   private String content;
   //get, set
}

class AH {
   private String name;
   private List<RH> rs = new ArrayList<RH>();
   //get, set
}

class RH {
   private String content;
   //get, set
}
```

How to configure dozer to map no only name field (it's mapped correctly) from A to AH but also map automatically collection of R to collection of RH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dozer handles this automatically. My fault, there were no getters and setters.